# Does fork() immediately copy the entire process heap in Linux?

Tags: linux, fork

A [`fork()` system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) clones a child process from the running process. The two processes are identical except for their PID.

Naturally, if the processes are just reading from their heaps rather than writing to it, copying the heap would be a huge waste of memory.

Is the entire process heap copied? Is it optimized in a way that only writing triggers a heap copy?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The *entirety* of `fork()` is implemented using mmap / copy on write.

This not only affects the heap, but also shared libraries, stack, BSS areas.

Which, incidentally, means that fork is a extremely lightweight operation, until the resulting 2 processes (parent and child) actually start writing to memory ranges. This feature is a major contributor to the lethality of fork-bombs - you end up with way too many processes before kernel gets overloaded with page replication and differentiation.

You'll be hard-pressed to find in a modern OS an example of an operation where kernel performs a hard copy (device drivers being the exception) - it's just far, far easier and more efficient to employ VM functionality.

Even `execve()` is essentially "please mmap the binary / ld.so / whatnot, followed by execute" - and the VM handles the actual loading of the process to RAM and execution. Local uninitialized variables end up being mmaped from a 'zero-page' - special read-only copy-on-write page containing zeroes, local initialized variables end up being mmaped (copy-on-write, again) from the binary file itself, etc.

Comment: One notable exception is Java processes. Search for *"fork java memory"* and you will find dozens of issues affecting large [server JVM](https://gist.github.com/pmahoney/1970815) or [embedded JVM](http://bryanmarty.com/2012/01/14/forking-jvm/) trying to execute a small shell command and miserably crashing on a *"Cannot allocate memory"* exception (these are just random links, this issue is systemic to the Java environments). This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11059525/3248253) accuses the JVM's garbage collector & JIT compiler from keeping processes memory from being shared.

Comment: Although this is absolutely correct, it may be useful to note that `fork()` used to copy the entire thing, so it wasn't always as lightweight as it is now. That's the reason for the existence of the `vfork()` system call which, nowadays, is largely useless and the speedup it provides is negligible.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf Wouldn’t shelling out immediately exec after the fork, thus not giving time to the garbage collector to dirty the memory pages?

Answer (score 35):

The Linux kernel does implement Copy-on-Write when `fork()` is called. When the syscall is executed, the pages that the parent and child share are marked read-only.

If a write is performed on the read-only page, it is then copied, as the memory is no longer identical between the two processes. Therefore, if only read-operations are being performed, the pages will not be copied at all.

Comment: +1 Thanks! 1. Could you please provide reference links? 2. Is the heap copied entirely, or in parts?

Comment: 2. - In pages :) The kernel has very little understanding of what "heap" is - for the kernel, it's just a bunch of mmapped private pages, that the libc allocators handle as it please.

Comment: Is this really a fork-bomb necessarily? It seems to me that rather than forking the current process, this code will create more instances of the same program that execute from start rather than from the next instruction after the `fork()` call.

Comment: @mmk FYI, I was quite surprised by your "Interesting side-note:" and so I tested (on Linux 3.2.0) to see, and it does not appear to be true. I used `/proc/self/pagemap` to determine the virtual address to physical page mapping for the purposed of the test. As I expected, if the grand-child and only the grand-child writes the shared page, then the parent and original child continue to share it. Only the grand-child ends up with a private copy.

Comment: @Celada. Hmm. I had read this somewhere, and I don't remember the kernel version it was referring to (probably an older one?), so, it may no longer be valid.

Comment: Regardless, I'm removing it since it isn't valid anymore

Answer (score 13):

Linux does Copy-on-Write.  As `fork` creates a new process, the allocated pages are marked as readonly and shared between the parent and child.  When either of them tries to modify a page, a page fault is generated resulting in copying the page and adjusting the page table appropriately.